# Javascript switch case that runs code when any case is true?

Tags: javascript

I have a standard switch case block:

```
switch(variable) {
    case "option1":
        alert("Option 1");
        break;
    case "option2":
        alert("Option 2");
        break;
}
```

And I would like to run this code:

```
alert("Any Option");
```

Is there a simple way to run this code when ***either*** of the cases match, without adding the code to every case, and ***without*** rechecking "variable" (i.e. not using an if statement after the switch)?

Comment: That would run both the Option 1 and Option 2 alerts, I'm looking here to run another piece of code such as alert("Both options")

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't think so. If you remove the first, then the case for option2 will erroneously execute when option1 is matched. If the second, then the code won't run if option1 was matched. If both, then the case for option2 will erroneously execute when option1 is matched.

Comment: @TinyGiant No... That simply creates fall-through. It will alert Option 1, Option 2, etc.

Comment: I misunderstood. No, you cannot do that. You would have to run another separate check. You can do the opposite (if no matches then `default`)

Comment: @TinyGiant Edited to make more clear but thank you, I don't suppose there's any doc or external source to confirm?

Comment: Do you want to run `alert("option n")` **and** `alert("Both Options")`?

Comment: @mhodges Yes I'm looking to run both the code within the case and the code if any case is true

Comment: If you want to run the same code when **either** case matches, put the code in both case blocks.

Comment: @DaveRager Also trying to avoid that but valid suggestion, I'll edit the question again. This is a simplified example but really I have more than two cases, trying to avoid having all the duplicate code for maintainability's sake

Comment: Why even bother using `switch` in this case? A simple `if(value) { if(value == 'option'1) { alert('Option 1'); } if(value == 'option2') { alert('Option 2'); } alert('Any Option'); }` would fit your case.

Comment: @Mackija how about setting a flag within the cases that you want to run the extra code, then after the switch, check the flag and run it there. This way you won't have to check the possibilities of variable again, just a single boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of **really** hacky ways to do what you are suggesting (named do loops with break/continue, recursive functions with switch statements, etc.) but the cleanest would be to use a function, like so:

```js
var variable = "option1";

function checkValue (val) {
    switch (variable) {
        case "option1":
            alert("Option 1");
            return true;
        case "option2":
            alert("Option 2");
            return true;
        default: 
            return false;
    }
}

if (checkValue(variable)) {
    // run common code
    alert("Any option");
}
```

Comment: Clever, I'm going to do some testing as this has given me an idea for another method. If that doesn't work I'll mark yours as the answer

Comment: @Mackija Didn't mean to have the "common" case in there. I was testing some other stuff out, woops.

Comment: @le_m Yeah, just realized I accidentally left it in there. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Not directly with a `switch` statement. See [The Switch Statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-switch-statement), ECMAScript 2016 standard.

In particular:

- [Runtime Semantics: Switch Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-switch-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation)
- [Runtime Semantics: CaseBlockExpression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-caseblockevaluation)

The language spec does not contain the feature that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A labeled block allows you to break out of it at any time. If you break in the `default` case, you can run some code following the `switch` statement when either of the cases match and without rechecking the variable, as requested:

```js
let variable = prompt("option1 or option2?");

select: {
  switch(variable) {
    case "option1":
        alert("Option 1");
        break;
    case "option2":
        alert("Option 2");
        break;
    default:
        break select;
  }
  alert("Both Options");
}
```

However, I don't recommend this! Labels make the code execution path less clear. Above code is not readable. Rechecking the variable is a better approach.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, "select" is a block of code. If variable is either "option1" or "option2" then it'll break, but **only** out of the switch. If it is neither, then it'll go to the default which breaks out of the "select" block and skip over the "Both options" alert?

Could you also clarify what you mean by less clear? Is it just because of readability?

Comment: @Mackija You got it right. With *less clear* I mean that I as a reader of such code have a hard time following possible code execution paths given all possible values of `variable`. This makes it hard to understand this code or spot bugs and even harder to modify it without accidentally introducing some flaws. Unless you have to write hyper-optimized code I suggest going with more explicit, descriptive style and a single execution path (an if-branch here and there is fine) without jumps.

Answer (score 1):

Why not making a function called by both cases?

```
switch(variable) {
case "option1":
    dualAlert("Option 1");
    break;
case "option2":
    dualAlert("Option 2");
    break;
}

function dualAlert(text){
    alert(text);
    alert('Common Alert');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think i would ever use the pattern you described, nonetheless something like this could suit your needs.

```
/**
 * Use this method to simulate a "finally" statement in a
 * method that resembles a switch
 *
 * @param {*} value - The value to compare
 * @param {Array<*, boolean, function>} options - The collection of switch statements
 *   First value is the value to compare against the original value
 *   Second value specifies if this statement should behave like a break at its end
 *   Third value is the action to take when the value matches
 * @param {function} finallyFn - The method which is run if any statement was executed
 */
function switchWithFinally(value, options, finallyFn) {
    var matched = false,
        breakSwitch = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if(!breakSwitch || value === options[i][0]) {
            options[i][2]();
            matched = true;
            breakSwitch = options[i][1];
        }
    }
    if(matched) finallyFn();
}

/**
 * Example call, should return
 *   Option 2
 *   Option 3
 *   Any option
 */
switchWithFinally(
    'option2',
    [
        ['option1', true, function() {
            console.log('Option 1');
        }],
        ['option2', false, function() {
            console.log('Option 2');
        }],
        ['option3', true, function() {
            console.log('Option 3');
        }]
    ],
    function() {
        console.log('Any option');
    }
);
```

Comment: +1 for this method because it is quite abstract and allows use of different functions/options on each call. For this particular case though I am only looking for a single static set of options, with one "Any option" function

Comment: In that case you just need to set all the second array values within the options array to `true` - this method is just trying to preserve the `break` behavior of the original switch statement but is entirely optional.